# Pre-made rain cap for plumbing vent? (Preventing rust-through of galvanized pipe in the walls)

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent, old-house

Are pre-made rain caps made for plumbing waste vents?

My house was built 1938 with galvanized DWV pipes which have a series of elbows before reaching the roof. All such elbows retain a certain amount of rain or dew water.  I quite incidentally discovered one elbow is paper thin at the bottom:

[image: Rusty drain waste pipe galvanized]

The run is more or less sloped.
See also:
[Covering / Cap over DWV vent pipe](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/58412/covering-cap-over-dwv-vent-pipe)
This is 1.5 inch pipe.

Comment: [These](http://www.squirrelgard.com/images/sg-vent.jpg) type of caps are normally used for gas combustion vents (like on a gas water heater, because they are metal pipes), but there's no reason you couldn't use it on a drain waste vent.  Does that work?

Comment: Three-quarters of a century in there's probably not much point to protecting the pipes now. They'll always be moist simply due to condensation from vent activity. I assume that you'll replace the run in the photo. How many does that leave?

Comment: @isherwood, that leaves four more, all buried in the attic. The run in the photo I will abandon in place and cap the top.  The rest are inaccessible without major work.

Comment: Unless you live in monsoon territory, the amount of rain entering through the stack is negligible, and you can't do much about the condensation from below. I have never seen a cap on a plumbing vent in my life, and I live in a rainy area. If the pipes are rotting, replace them but a cap is likely not the answer to anything.

Answer (score 2):

I used a quick and very cheap solution, taking a standard plastic elbow and jamming it on to form a vent cap:

[image: DIY rain cap for 1.5" plumbing vent]

This will not affect vent operation, but will keep a large fraction of the rainwater out of the pipe, potentially extending the pipe lifetime by a few decades.  This also has a presumably minor benefit of keeping rainwater out of the sewer.

Comment: Funny, this didn't occur to me when researching this topic, even though we have these on the vents for our septic/leech field. On those we have 2 elbows in an upside-down U, so the hole points downward. Might be a good idea on roofs as well?